# How to remove pragma busy_timeout value from sqlite3 command result in bash?

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell

```
result=$(sqlite3 sample.db "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE value='sample';")
echo $result
```

Result is `1`.
Because of "Database is locked" error I changed the code:

```
result=$(sqlite3 sample.db "pragma busy_timeout=20000; SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE value='sample';")
echo $result
```

But now the result is:

```
20000 1
```

I don't want `busy_timeout` value in the result.
I want the result to be `1`.
How can I do that by editing `sqlit3` commands?

Comment: Why is it locked (are there multiple concurrent connections)? Try `sqlite3 -cmd '.timeout 2000' sample.db` or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47920).

Comment: @user4157124 Most pragmas are only in effect for the duration of the connection they're made in. So setting the timeout in one `sqlite3` process isn't going to affect a different one.

Comment: (OP, try changing the database to use [WAL mode](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) if you have a lot of concurrent users of the database.)

Comment: @user4157124 Concurrent connections cause **Database is locked** Error, thanks for your help, I'm checking your solution.

Comment: @Shawn Based on your comment, it seems your solution is suitable for a lot of concurrent users accessing DB, But in my case just two concurrent scripts use DB, Do you think using WAL mode is a good idea?

Comment: @Shawn That was understood (and not intended). In WAL mode instead of `SQLITE_LOCKED`, `SQLITE_BUSY` would sporadically be encountered (requiring `busy_timeout` pragma either way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user4157124
**Sqlite3** command must edit as below:
`result=$(sqlite3 -cmd ".timeout 20000" sample.db "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE value='sample';")`
It prevents **Database is locked** Error and the **result** varibale doesn't combine with the timeout value.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the format of what's been saved in the `result` variable.

In the current code we see:

```
$ echo $result
20000 1
```

Since the variable reference was not wrapped in double quotes we can't tell if `sqlite3` places a space or newline between the two numbers. So, let's look at addressing both possibilities ...

**Variable wrapped in double quotes shows a space between numbers:**

```
$ echo "$result"
20000 1

# one idea:

$ read -r timeout result < <(sqlite3 ....)
$ typeset -p timeout result
declare -- timeout="20000"
declare -- result="1"
```

**Variable wrapped in double quotes shows a newline between numbers:**

```
$ echo "$result"
20000
1

# one idea:

$ result=$(sqlite3 .... | tail -1)
                        ^^^^^^^^^
$ typeset -p result
declare -- result="1"
```

---

Another option that allows OP to maintain the current code plus one new assignment:

```
$ result=$(sqlite3 ....)
$ result="${result##*[[:space:]]}"
```

Testing:

```
$ result="20000
1"
$ result="${result##*[[:space:]]}"
$ typeset -p result
declare -- result="1"

$ result="20000 1"
$ result="${result##*[[:space:]]}"
$ typeset -p result
declare -- result="1"
```